# Pass Servlet output to JSON variable

Tags: json, jsp, servlets, extjs

Somebody help.. How can I pass the string value of my Servlet output to my ExtJS using JSON..

My Servlet has an output like this;

```
[{"Name":"No Top Specified"},
{"Name":"No Bottom Specified"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B HAPPY PREMIUM TOP"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B SHARB B TOP"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B TROPIX TOP"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B BOTTOM 351.00"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B SHARBATLY BOTTOM"},
{"Name":"13KG F/B TROPIX BOTTOM"},
{"Name":"14KG F/B ORGANIC TOP"},
{"Name":"14KG F/B BOTTOM"}]
```

These data came from my database.. I want to know what would be the syntax of my ExtJS to make these data the data of my ExtJS powered combobox. Thanks.:)

This is my service method..

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

int y = 1;
while(rs.next()){
int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {
String column_value = rs.getString(i);
obj.put("Name", column_value);
response.setContentType("application/jsons");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

}

jsonarray.put(obj).toString();      

y++;
}   
System.out.println(jsonarray);
response.getWriter().println(jsonarray);
rs.close();                                                              
pst.close();
```

Comment: modifier your servlet to output: {"items":[{"Name": ... ]} and use a store/modell to point to your servlet.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @skuntsel: not yet.. :(

Comment: So what is the problem right now?

Comment: @skuntsel: Still the same.. I cant pass my JSON Data from servlet to my JSP page.. :(( Kinda frustrating..

Comment: Show `service` method of your servlet and the jsp view.

Comment: @skuntsel: I have added my service class above.. Hope im doing it right.. Sorry if it took to long for me to reply..

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to return a proper JSON from your servlet and later handle it somewhere with ExtJS.

Servlet method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException { 
    List<Data> data = ...;//populate data from your database in key-value pairs
    String json = new Gson().toJson(data);//or generate JSON the other way
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Data class:

```
public class Data {
    private String label;//getter+setter
    private String value;//getter+setter
}
```

Handling data in your jsp with, for example, the following javascript:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/servleturl',
        success: function(response){
            var states = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            var values = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['label', 'value'],
                data : states
            });
            var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                fieldLabel: 'Choose your shape: ',
                store: values,
                displayField: 'value',
                valueField: 'label',
                queryMode: 'local',
                renderTo: 'wrapper'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and the following `div` in your jsp:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can populate your combobox 'at once', when you initially render your view, by using `request.setAttribute(data)` and later processing it in your jsp, and not via an AJAX call to another servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var servlet = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['Name'],
    data : [
        {"Name":"No Top Specified"},
        {"Name":"No Bottom Specified"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B HAPPY PREMIUM TOP"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B SHARB B TOP"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B TROPIX TOP"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B BOTTOM 351.00"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B SHARBATLY BOTTOM"},
        {"Name":"13KG F/B TROPIX BOTTOM"},
        {"Name":"14KG F/B ORGANIC TOP"},
        {"Name":"14KG F/B BOTTOM"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: servlet,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: 'Name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```